# How to implement a view (list) with a random number of independent reactive forms

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In a paginated list view (*ngFor) we would like to render an instance of the "same" reactive form, one per row. All forms are independent, therefore FormArray doesn't seem to fit. In other words, we don't want to have an outer form.

Are there any approaches for that?

Comment: Can you please provide a little code or a picture to understand easier your question ?

Comment: you can have an array of FormGroup (not a FormArray): myForms=FormGroup[[]=[];this.myForms.push(new FormGroup(...); or this.myForms.push(this.fb.group({prop1:..,prop2:...});